# Custom Functions with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4.1

How to use  Custom Functions with Entity Framework?
I'm trying to Call model-Defined Functions with Entity Framework. I use .Net Framework 4.5
I'm opening the Entity Model (.edmx) file in XML. I'm adding the following code inside 'edmx:StorageModels' section:

```
  <Function Name="YearsSinceNow" ReturnType="int">
    <Parameter Name="date" Type="datetime" />
    <DefiningExpression>
      Year(CurrentDateTime()) - Year(date)
    </DefiningExpression>
  </Function>

  </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
```

I'm getting the error 'Unrecognized schema element: DefiningExpression'.
Also I've tried to apply this code inside edmx:ConceptualModels section. And I've got an error 'Unrecognized schema element Function'

Comment: Are you sure you tried to put this in the `Schema` element inside `edmx:ConceptualModels` as that is where it should go.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your definition as follows (define it in the conceptual model not the storage model):

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd456857%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<Function Name="YearsSinceNow" ReturnType="Edm.Int32">
  <Parameter Name="date" Type="Edm.DateTime" />
  <DefiningExpression>
    Year(CurrentDateTime()) - Year(date)
  </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

Next, add the following method to your application and use an EdmFunctionAttribute to map it to the conceptual model function similar to:

```
[EdmFunction("MyModelName", "YearsSinceNow")]
public static int YearsSinceNow(DateTime date)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

Add a common language runtime (CLR) method to your application that maps to the function defined in the conceptual model. To map the method, you must apply an EdmFunctionAttribute to the method. Note that the NamespaceName and FunctionName parameters of the attribute are the namespace name of the conceptual model and the function name in the conceptual model respectively. Function name resolution for LINQ is case sensitive.

Have a read of [How to: Define Custom Functions in the Conceptual Model (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd456812%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

For a Function element, which you can add to the Schema element in the Conceptual Model Content section of an .edmx file to define a custom function.

Comment: Indeed, but as you commented it should go in the conceptual model.

Comment: I tried in conceptual model inside and outside schema element without success. Also [EdmFunction("MyModelName", "YearsSinceNow")] gives 'cannot access internal constructor 'EdmFunction' here.

Comment: You get that error when calling from inside a linq query? You cannot call it directly.

Comment: I'm trying to create the class.     public static class EdmFunctions
    {
        [EdmFunction("TestModel", "FullName")]
        public static string FullName()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This function is only for L2E query.");
        }
    }

Comment: Hmmm.... Are you using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction and not something like System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction?

Comment: You referenced the wrong namespace.The right namespace is ‘using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;’.@user2273044